# How to set up a search input that will update the data on another page/component with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have static data that I display on the table page. In total, I have several pages in the application.

data.json:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Item 1",
  },
  {
    "title": "Item 2",
  }
...
]
```

Table page:

```
import data from '@/data.json';

import Header from '@/components/header/header.js';
import Table from '@/components/table/table.js';

export default function TablePage(props) {

  return (
    <div>

      <Header data={data} />
      <main>
        <Table data={data}></Table>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have two components on this page.

Header Component:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import styles from './header.module.css';

function search(e, data, router) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const string = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
  const result = data.filter(item => item.title.match(string));
  router.push('/table_page');
}

export default function Header (props) {
  const data = props.data;
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <div className={styles.search}>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => {search(e, data, router)}}>
          <button type='submit'></button>
          <input type='search' placeholder='Type song or artist name'/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Table Component:

```
import styles from './table.module.css';

export default function table({data}) {

  const renderItems = arr => {
    const items =  arr.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {item.title}
          </td>  
        </tr>
      )
    })

    return items 
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.table}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Title
            </th>         
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {renderCollabs(data)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I want is that when a user types in the input (on any page), he is redirected to the table page, and the table is rendered with filtered data (based on the input).

In the `search` function, I managed to get the new data and redirect to the desired page. But how to redraw the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect from `Header` with a query parameter, called `search` for example, with its value the typed value in the input.

Header component:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import styles from './header.module.css';

function search(e, router) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const string = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
  router.push({ pathname: "/table_page", query: { search: string } });
}

export default function Header (props) {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <div className={styles.search}>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => {search(e, router)}}>
          <button type='submit'></button>
          <input type='search' placeholder='Type song or artist name'/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Table page:

```
import data from "@/data.json";

import Header from "@/components/header/header.js";
import Table from "@/components/table/table.js";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function TablePage(props) {
  const [tableDate, updateTableDate] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    updateTableDate(() => {
      if (!router.isReady) {
        return [];
      }
      const result = router.query.search
        ? data.filter((item) => item.title.toLowerCase().match(router.query.search.toLowerCase()))
        : data;
      return result;
    });
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Table data={tableDate}></Table>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```